# Delphi 2007: IDE Model View: Generate Documentation missing?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

In my Delphi 2007 IDE I've activated Model Support.
In the Model View, I can see all my classes and open an UML diagram for those classes.
But how can I generate documentation?
There is no `Generate Documentation` in the Tools dialog, and also none when I right-click items in the Model View.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Generate Documentation* is part of Delphi 2007 Enterprise. The Professional edition is lacking this feature.